# How to Prevent ansible from evaluating variable values

Tags: linux, ansible

I am calling a playbook from another playbook, as per my requirement I need to pass a variable something like `{{ abc }}`, now I want to stop evaluation of this variable from my outer playbook.

Like in bash, we can stop variable evaluation by using single quotes.

```
----
A='${abc}';
echo $A

O/P=>
${abc}
----
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: Do you mean you simply want to have raw jinja2 markers in your variable value ? Try this oneliner as an example: `ansible localhost -m debug -a var=test_var -e test_var="{% raw %}{{ whatever }}{% endraw %}"` - https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping

Comment: Use raw command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agree with @zeitounator.
Pls use: "{% raw %}{{ whatever }}{% endraw %}"